# How to trim each string element in the string array without using loop?

Tags: c#, .net, arrays, string

```
var gender = from row in excel.Worksheet()
             select row["Gender *"].Value.ToString();
string[] genderArray = gender.ToArray().Distinct().ToArray();
```

in this case the content of genderArray are { "F" , "M" , "M "}

i want that genderArray should only contain { "F" , "M" }

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
var gender = (from row in excel.Worksheet()
                 select  row["Gender *"].Value.ToString()) ;
    string[]  genderArray = gender.ToArray().Distinct().Select(g=>g.Trim()).ToArray();
```

You can also do the .Trim in the first query against Value.ToString().Trim(). 
Edited: I might have misplaced the select in the query.

Answer (score 4):

```
var gender = (from row in excel.Worksheet() 
            select row["Gender *"].Value.ToString().Trim()) ;
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using [`String.Trim()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t97s7bs3.aspx)?

```
var gender = (from row in excel.Worksheet()
             select  row["Gender *"].Value.ToString().Trim()) ;
string[]  genderArray = gender.ToArray().Distinct().ToArray();
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's how I would tackle it:

```
var data = new List<string> {"F", "M", "M "};
var gender = data.Select(x => x.Trim()).Distinct().ToArray();
```

Or if you prefer:

```
var gender = (from x in data select x.Trim()).Distinct().ToArray();
```